# Issue with Currency field in Lightning Datatable

Tags: lightning-datatable

I have a lightning datatable with editable currency field with currency set as Japanese Yen (¥). I selected multiple records in datatable and tried to edit the currency field. The current symbol shows USD ($) instead of Japanese Yen (¥). Ideally it should show same currency symbol as in currency field as this is taking the logged in user currency. Kindly let me know how to fix this issue?

[image: Lightning Datatable With Currency Field]

[image: After Selecting Multiple Records and trying to edit currecny field]